How to establish this inequality in Algebraic Topology and Combinatorics?
I'm reading this paper. In the proof of Theorem 1.1, they establish the inequality $k(n-k)\geq 2(n-2)$.
$\Gamma$ is the smallest connected component with $k$ vertices and there is atleast $k(n-k)$ number of antifacets. Also, we have $k\geq 2$ and $n-k\geq k\geq 2$. But in the proof they claim $\bar{e}(\Delta)\geq k(n-k)\geq 2(n-2).$
My attempt: $k\geq 2$ gives $n-k\leq n-2$. Also, $k\leq \frac{n}{2}$.
If $k=2$, $k(n-k)=2(n-2)$ hence the proof.
$k\geq 3$ implies $n\geq 6$,
$n-k\geq n-\frac{n}{2}\geq \frac{n}{2}$. Then,  $k(n-k)\geq \frac{3n}{2}>\frac{3}{2}(n-2).$
But I'm unable to proceed the proof.

Observe that $k(n-k)-2(n-2)=kn-k^2-2n+4=(n-k-2)(k-2)$.

What is $\Gamma$? What's a vertex? What's an antifacet? Please keep in mind our guidelines for formatting and writing your post, where it says Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.

As @TravorLZH wrote, showing $k(n-k) \geq 2(n-2)$ is equivalent to showing
$$k(n−k)−2(n−2)=kn−k^2−2n+4 =(n-k-2)(k-2) \geq 0,$$
which follows from $n-k \geq 2$ and $k \geq 2$.
A perhaps more intuitive way to see it is as follows: for fixed $n$, the product $x(n-x)$ gets larger when $x$ gets closer to $n/2$ (in other words, of all rectangles with a given perimeter, the more square-like ones have the larger areas). And $k$ is closer than 2 to $n/2$ when $n-2 \geq k \geq 2$.
